# How do I disable ships?

Tags: naev

So far, all I have been able to do is destroy ships.  I have been unable to disable any ship for boarding.  Do I need any particular kind of weapons or loadout or do I have to stop shooting after a certain point?

Comment: What is this game, and how do I go about playing it?

Comment: This game is an absolutely wonderful space trading game, very well made. I got it through Desura, but you can also get it [here](http://blog.naev.org/)

Comment: @Fluttershy its a great game, enjoying it a lot.  Been looking for a new escape velocity like game for a while and this game definitely scratches that itch.

Comment: I was about to say that it sounds a lot like Escape Velocity of old, when I realized that the name is Na **ev**. I see what you did there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get a weapon with a large amount of disable damage. These are:
- Ion Cannon
- Heavy Ion Cannon
- Heavy Ion Turret
- EMP Grenades
- Medusa Missiles

Then, you simply need to whale on the target ship with one of the above till the blue bar is filled up. The tutorial covers this as well. The best depends on what ship you're flying, but Medusa Missiles and their launchers are cheap, plentiful, and you can fit them on light ships. I'd say go with them. If you do, make sure to do the missile tutorial to figure out how they work.

References

http://wiki.naev.org/wiki/Disabling

http://forum.naev.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=706

Comment: would you recommend any particular ship to use for disabling?  So far I have ~2m credits to work with

Comment: @yx. http://wiki.naev.org/wiki/Admonisher - Pretty solid.  I'm pretty sure It's like 700,000.  Heavy Ion Cannon if you can.

Comment: great!  thanks for the help!  Now I have to go look for that ship.

Comment: @yx. The other nice thing about it, is it has -3% Energy Usage for Cannons.  That *should* include the Heavy Ion Cannon :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to do enough damage to disable them (like 25%) with out killing them too.  Its a balancing act.